# Django NoReverseMatch at / with arguments '('',)'

Tags: python, django, web, reverse

I have:

```
path('new/', views.new, name='new_without_arg'),
path('new/<str:arg>', views.new_with_arg, name='new_with_arg')
```

in my urls.py and when I have 'new_with_arg' in a template:

`<a href="{% url 'new_with_arg' subject %}">New Subject</a>`

I get:

Reverse for 'new_with_arg' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new/(?P[^/]+)$']

My views.py is:

```
def new(request):
    return render(request, 'notes/new.html')

def new_with_arg(request, arg):

    if(arg == 'task'):
        return render(request, 'notes/new_task.html')

    elif(arg == 'room'):
        return render(request, 'notes/new_room.html')

    elif(arg == 'subject'):
        return render(request, 'notes/new_subject.html')
    
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('new_without_arg'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept your own answer (tick the check-mark next to your answer after a 48 hours waiting period). In this way your question stops from showing up as _unanswered_. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it had to be:

`<a href="{% url 'new_with_arg' 'subject' %}">New Subject</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing subject variable from views.py to html file?

Comment: No, no matter what word I use instead of 'subject', it shows the same error